# How to make an iframe override the html of the base page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am currently doing this to inject an iframe:

```
var iFrame  = document.createElement ("iframe");
iFrame.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ("chrome.html");
iFrame.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
iFrame.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
iFrame.setAttribute("style", "border:none; width:100%; height:20%");
document.body.insertBefore (iFrame, document.body.firstChild);
```

though it works well, it injects the iframe on top of the web page. Thus, if you've scrolled down, then you've to scroll up to view the iframe. I was wondering how do I add an iframe on top of the page, where it acts like a dropdown(drops on top of the page) and disappears after scrolling.

Comment: You mean NOT disappears after scrolling?

Comment: Not really. I mean disappear after scrolling, or when you start scrolling.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Yes, not disappear when you start scrolling, but goes away in 3 or 4 seconds of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
function checkScroll()
{
    //remove the iframe
    //iFrame.parentNode.removeChild(iFrame);

    //or remove after 2 secs
    setTimeout(function(){ iFrame.parentNode.removeChild(iFrame); }, 2000);

    //off the scroll listener
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', checkScroll); 
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/QF3qY/1/

Comment: Thanks. But how do I add an iFrame on the absolute top position?

Comment: I make it fixed position(see css), so it can be visible when scroll

Comment: The css completely messes up the position of the iframe on various websites.

Comment: I see, you need to target the specific iframe you just created, right? add iFrame.style.position="fixed"; see here http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/QF3qY/3/

Answer (score 1):

You create an empty container that sits on top of your page (z-index, absolute positioning) and you add your ifram there instead of the body's first child. You can hide the container onscroll via JavaScript.